# How convert a String response to an iterable object

Tags: java, android, json, rest, android-volley

I am trying to call a rest end point using Volley (HTTP library) in Android/Java app. Here is my code,

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="https://covid19datasl.herokuapp.com/countries";


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println(response);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        });
```

But it gives me an String a response like this,

```
[{"country":"USA","countryCode":"US"},{"country":"India","countryCode":"IN"},{"country":"Brazil","countryCode":"BR"}]
```

How do I convert this `String` to an itaratable object?

Comment: Do you want a list, dictionary or what?

Comment: Well, that's JSON - so I'd use a JSON library to parse it.

Comment: Anything that can itarable would be fine.

Comment: I used Gson . But it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for any other libraries beside Volley.

Use Volleys [JsonArrayRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request#request-json) for retrieving `JSONArray` responses.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

String url = "http://my-json-feed";

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        // do something with the response
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO: Handle error
    }
});

// Add request to queue 
queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```