# Error when parsing json array from url android retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit, jsonparser

i implemented retrofit 2 in order to get a list of users and it worked fine but the result came as an array of json like this after Log.e method in android:

```
E/USERS LIST: User{id=1, name='aaaaaaaaaa', lastName='vvvvvvvvvvvvv', password='123456', email='f@dsdds.com', phone='97475414'}
E/USERS LIST: User{id=2, name='aaaaaaaaaa', lastName='vvvvvvvvvvvvv', password='123456', email='f@dss.com', phone='97475414'}
    User{id=3, name='aaaaaaaaaa', lastName='vvvvvvvvvvvvv', password='123456', email='f@dsbvcs.com', phone='97475414'}
    User{id=4, name='aaaaaaaaaa', lastName='vvvvvvvvvvvvv', password='123456', email='f@dsddse.com', phone='97475414'}
    User{id=5, name='aaaaaaaaaa', lastName='vvvvvvvvvvvvv', password='123456', email='f@dsddsex.com', phone='97475414'}
    User{id=6, name='sadasda', lastName='fadsa', password='123456', email='fares@fares.com', phone='73333333'}
    User{id=7, name='sadasda', lastName='fadsa', password='123456', email='fares@farese.com', phone='73333333'}
    User{id=8, name='sadasd', lastName='dsdsa', password='Zakataka', email='dss@dsds.com', phone='333333333333'}
    User{id=9, name='eeeeeeee', lastName='dddddd', password='dddddddddddd', email='f@ffe.com', phone='33333333333333'}
E/USERS LIST: User{id=10, name='sssss', lastName='eeeee', password='123456', email='faresbenslama95@gmail.com', phone='333333333333'}
    User{id=11, name='dssds', lastName='fedds', password='"""""""""""""', email='faresbenslama95@gmail.coms', phone='44444444444'}
    User{id=12, name='sadsad', lastName='dsad', password='Zakataka', email='faresbenslama95@gmail.comse', phone='555555555555'}
    User{id=13, name='sdsds', lastName='ffsd', password='ddddddddddd', email='faresbenslama95@gmail.comh', phone='555555555555'}
```

my method in android:

```
public void getUsersList(){
        Call<List<User>> call = apiService.getUsers();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    users = response.body();
                  
                    for(User user: users){
                        Log.e("USERS LIST", user.toString());
                    }

                    //listView.setAdapter(new UserAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_user, list));
                }
            }
```

what i am searching for is getting array of users without json
i am seaching everywhere but everytime i try something in the tutorials , a lot of problems happens

so please how to do this???? i need it as an array of Users not like the result array i got from retrofit

Comment: use gson or moshi libraray to convert json to java objects

Comment: i tried it but i think i did not know how to work with it correctly

Comment: Have a look at Android Volley its got a real easy implementation for requesting JSONArray data https://stackoverflow.com/a/65000933/1133011

Comment: it's with volley , not with retrofit , is there any way to parse response.body() ?