# Parse JSON Object without key in Android Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Below is my JSON Output. I'm using Volley in Android

```
[
 {
   "id":"01",
   "content":"Just Hello"
 }
]
```

My API URL: https://jsonkeeper.com/b/F7WB

I'm try to fetch in automatically when the App loads.
Also I want to refetch when the button is clicked using OnClickLister.

I don't know why It's not displaying the fetched text. Nor listening to button click.

I have done upto here. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Below is my whole source code.

```
package com.example.app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;


import org.json.JSONArray;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView qts;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        qtss = findViewById(R.id.qts);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        MainActivity.this.jsonParse();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.this.jsonParse();
            }
        });
    }

    private void jsonParse() {
        String url = "https://jsonkeeper.com/b/F7WB";
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        qtss.setText(response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO: Handle error

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How convert a String response to an iterable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000363/how-convert-a-string-response-to-an-iterable-object)

Comment: The above link is what you want , you need to use `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`. Also ensure you have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest

Comment: `MainActivity.java:55: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int qtss.setText(response.toString(content));` I'm getting this error

Comment: Whats `content`?

Comment: I want to set the `content` of JSON to the textview

Comment: So why not just do `qtss.setText(response.toString())`

Comment: It's not working. Idk why. TextView is not set as the JSON `content` Value or not even setting on button click.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `onClick` and in the `onResponse` and see whats happening. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: I'm getting this error `E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.app    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

Comment: That has nothing to do with the code you have shown

Comment: omg, I'm not getting any error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in `onResponse` does it hit the breakpoint. If it does hover your mouse over `response` is there data?

Comment: Yes. I did. Unfortunately no error in debugger when putting break point in `onResponse`

Comment: You not suppose to get an error, its suppose to break/pause on the line of code . Did you read the link I said about breakpoints/debugging

Comment: Also your code doesn't make sense the variable is `qts` then later its `qtss` im wondering how it even runs at this point make sure they all named the same please